# How to do this type of aiming projectile?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make this aiming projectile for one of my games and wondering what is the best approach to achieve this. I want the motion aiming projectile with moving dots towards the pointing direction.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a LineRenderer for this purpose.

You can achieve the dotted line effect by supplying the LineRenderer with a dotted line texture and tiling it for a continuous dotted line effect.